# Photos are not loading in the app after adding the webpack

Tags: javascript, css, image, webpack

The images that I have previously loaded in the program are not loaded after adding the webpack
This is my webpack.config file:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "/src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundel.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /nod_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
  },
};
```

Do I need to include all the photos in the index.js file for the loader file to work?

Not loading the photos in the program is my main problem. It also helps to get the files from the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnMBU.png)e it was vague.

Comment: In webpack config, you specify, png, jpeg and gif for image format. But from screenshot it seems, you have **\*.svg** format image. Try to add .svg extension to webpack.config

Comment: In addition to what @SeLeCtRa said, can you also share how you are importing your images in your code?

Comment: The images are mainly used as the background in the css file, in the html file in the img tag